# Why does ExecuteNonQuery give back "Input is not valid in this context" (ASP.NET | Ole Db)?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to change a user's name. The current name and the new one are textbox inputs. On debugging, I get the exception that f.e. "JOHN" is not valid in this context. Why does this happen? It should expect a string and receives it. Where is the mistake?

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class Index : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = "...";

            OleDbCommand changeFirstName = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Usertable SET Name =" + @NewFN + " WHERE Name = " + @FN + "", con);
            changeFirstName.Parameters.Add("@NewFN", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = getNewFirstName.Text;
            changeFirstName.Parameters.Add("@FN", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = getFirstName.Text;

            con.Open();

            try
            {
                int i = changeFirstName.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }

            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the string concatenations in your query and write it like a single string. What database are you using? Name could be a reserved keyword

Comment: You're mixing the worst of both worlds - you're trying to use parameters but you're continuing to try to build up your query via string concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it now. Because it is OleDb I can not use @ in the Command string. Instead of @NewFN and @FN I have to use ?. On Parameter.Add I have to use @Name to give them a value. Here is an example:

```
OleDbCommand changeFirstName = new OleDbCommand (”UPDATE Usertable SET Name = ? WHERE Name = ?“);

changeFirstName.Parameters.Add(”@Name“, OleDbType.VarChar).Value = getNewFirstName.Text;
```

Answer (score 2):

The parameter tokens are part of the SQL and live inside it:

```
OleDbCommand changeFirstName = new OleDbCommand(
    "UPDATE Usertable SET Name = @NewFN WHERE Name = @FN", con);
```

Side notes:

- the connection and command are both `IDisposable` and should use `using`
- when possible, prefer the provider-specific provider over OleDB - for example, if you're connecting to SQL-Server, use `SqlConnection` / `SqlCommand`
- you may find tools like "Dapper" save you a *lot* of work here

Example of all 3 combined:

```
using(var con = new SqlConnection("..."))
{
    con.Execute("UPDATE Usertable SET Name = @NewFN WHERE Name = @FN",
        new {
              NewFN = getNewFirstName.Text,
              FN = getFirstName.Text,
        });
}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks. I tried your first code example. Now I get the exception that ”@NewFN“ is not valid in this context. So it can‘t be part of SQL because now it doesn‘t even get the parameter value.

Comment: @Red'n'Black see also "when possible, prefer the provider-specific provider over OleDB" :)

Comment: unfortunately I can not use this snippet in my project, but i keep it in mind :)